# Браузер не сохраняет Cookie

Tags: cookie, express, axios, localhost

Помогите разобраться, почему браузер (Chrome и любые другие) не устанавливает cookie, несмотря на то, что присутствует соответствующий заголовок Set-Cookie в Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 345
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2020 21:15:53 GMT
ETag: W/"159-UXuykOchcveuYBb7xZpN5Luf3jU"
Set-Cookie: jwt=************; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 17 Apr 2020 21:15:53 GMT; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Локально приложение запускается с http://localhost:8080
Сервер с БД и прочей логикой на http://localhost:3000

При этом при работе с Postman все хорошо, cookie сохраняются, но если выполнять запросы с localhost:8080, то браузер не сохраняет cookie, несмотря на то, что необходимые заголовки получены.

Подобный вопрос задавался [здесь](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1553), но, к сожалению, для себя решения так и не нашел.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что не устанавливает?

Comment: Вкладка Application --> Cookies для http://localhost:8080 пусто

Answer (score 0):

**На стороне JS (клиента)**

Нужно включить настройку `credentials: 'include'` при передаче запросов. Для передачи `Cookies` и авторизационных заголовков.

Для `fetch`: `fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })`
Для `xhr`: `xhr.withCredentials = true`
Для `axios`: `axios.create({withCredentials: true})` или `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`

P.S. В зависимости от класса отправляемого запрос на бэк, настройка для включения `credentials` может отличаться.

**На стороне сервера**

Credentials "true" требует в `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` значение отличающееся от "*", поэтому задаём его жёстко:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site.com`

Передавать Cookie и Header аутентификацию:
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Можно почитать в документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials